# Least integer function and Greatest Integer Function Without using ceil() and Floor()

Tags: arithmetic, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I was wondering if there is any mathematical way to calculate **Least Integer** and **Greatest integer** without using predefined **Ceil() and Floor()** Function of Programming Language.

Comment: There certainly are ways (since ceil and floor are not implemented in hardware).  The language will have implemented them using just basic operations available at hardware level--$+,-,\times,\\$ and bit operations like AND/OR/XOR, etc.

Comment: There are a lot of easy ways to implement the functions badly.  E.g. (assuming $x>0$) subtract $1$ repeatedly until $0<x^\prime<1$ and count how many times you do this, say $n$ times.  Then the floor is $n$ and the ceil is $n+1$.

Comment: @TravisJ Exactly.But still i am not able to make expressions for ceil() and Floor().

Comment: E.g. python has [modf](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.modf) or one can work with binary representation of a floating point $m\cdot 2^e$ where $m$ and $e$ are binary integers itself.

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: What do you mean by "make expressions"?

Comment: @ChantryCargill c++

Comment: Why don't you want to use built-in functions in C++?

Comment: @TravisJ i am worried if they are slow!!

Comment: They will not be slow in c++, but I suppose you could do it yourself in assembly.

Comment: The standard function in the math library http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/ (including floor and ceil) will likely be far more optimized than anything you or I would write in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: They are as fast as a 1flop as hard-coded into a FPU in most cases.

Comment: @TravisJ Yes sir you are right.i think i should focus more on logic than in optimization.Thank you sir

Comment: I would be very surprised if the bottleneck in your code was a floor/ceil computation.  You are far better off to focus elsewhere (at least 99.999% of the time).

Answer (score 1):

You got good advise in the comments by TravisJ. You should not try to implement the simple math functions (sin,cos,exp,floor, etc.) yourself unless you really know what you are doing. These functions have been so optimized that beating them on speed is almost impossible (unless you can do with lower accuracy).

---

However, there is a 'simple' way to compute the floor (or ceil) by directly manipulating the [binary representation of the number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format):

$$a = (-1)^{\text{sign}}(1.b_{51}b_{50}...b_{0})_2 \times 2^{e-1023}$$

Just for fun, here is a method, made by [a collegue of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1061433/amaurea), that does this in c/c++:

```
int64_t myfloor(double a) {
  // a = sign * frac * 2^exp
  uint64_t raw = *(uint64_t*) &a;
  int sign = raw >> 63;
  int exp  = (int)(( raw >> 52) & 0x7ff ) - 0x3ff - 52;
  uint64_t frac = 1ull << 52 | raw & 0xfffffffffffffull;
  frac <<= 1;
  if(exp>=0) frac <<= exp;
  else frac >>= -exp;
  if(sign) frac += 1;
  frac >>= 1;
  return sign ? -(int64_t) frac : (int64_t) frac;
}
```

This method is, as you can test for yourself, much slower then the built-in method.

Comment: `*(uint64_t*) &a;` is undefined behaviour (at least in C, not entirely sure about C++) [section 6.5, clause 7]. A correct way (in C) is type punning via a union [sections 6.5, c 7 and 6.5.2.3, c 3, footnote 95], another correct way is via `memcpy`. The shifts are undefined behaviour if the absolute value of `exp` is not smaller than 64. The cast `(int64_t) frac` has an implementation-defined result, or raises an implementation-defined signal, if `frac >= 1ull << 63` [6.3.1.3, c 3] - but if the value of `a` is outside `int64_t`-range, you get garbage anyway, so this one's meh.